# How to store image files into mongo DB using script (if possible using GridFS)

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to store a student into mongo DB using script file.

```
mongo student create-student.js
```

in my script file I have written as follows

```
var student = { name :"Hussain",
                join-date : "23-10-2010",
                photo : "/path/to/file" //here user will give path to the image
}
db.student.save(student);
```

I have achieved same thing using GridFS using java, same way trying to achieve in script file.